# How to install Chromium masked package on Alpine Linux 3.8?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, chromium, alpine-linux

I am using Vagrant with VirtualBox, and running [Alpine 3.8](https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/alpine38) inside:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'generic/alpine38'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'generic/alpine38' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ep2018-workshop_default_1532787155941_48660
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
```

When trying to install `chromium`, I get an error message about a missing dependency masked in the community repository:

```
$ vagrant ssh
localhost:~$ sudo apk add --update chromium
fetch https://mirror.leaseweb.com/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://mirror.leaseweb.com/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  ttf-opensans-1.10-r0:
    masked in: @community
    satisfies: chromium-64.0.3282.168-r0[ttf-opensans]
  chromium-64.0.3282.168-r0:
    masked in: @community
    satisfies: world[chromium]
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apk add --update chromium@community
```

Or remove `@community` pin from `/etc/apk/repositories`. It's quite unusual configuration to have the official community repo pinned.

Comment: There was indeed `@community https://mirror.leaseweb.com/alpine/v3.8/community` in the `/etc/apk/repositories` of my 
[generic/alpine38](https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/alpine38) Vagrant box.